# How to merge (aggregate) nested model collections in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, collections, ember.js, ember-data

Consider this model:

```
Grandparent
  parents: DS.hasMany('parent')

Parent:
  grandparent: DS.belongsTo('grandparent')
  children: DS.hasMany('child')

Child:
  parent: DS.belongsTo('parent')
```

I want to add a computed property `children` to `Grandparent` model, in which I expect a collection of `Child` models (Grandparent.children = merge each Grandparent.parents.children).

How to do that?

For this example data:

```
Grandparent { id: 0, parents: [0, 1] }

Parent { id: 0, grandparent: 0, children: [0] }
Parent { id: 1, grandparent: 0, children: [1,2] }

Child { id: 0, parent: 0 }
Child { id: 1, parent: 1 }
Child { id: 2, parent: 1 }
```

I want `Grandparent.get('children')` to return children with ids [0, 1, 2].

**EDIT:**

```
App.Grandparent.reopen({
  grandchildren: function(){
    var result = [];
    this.get('parents').forEach(function(parent) {
      parent.get('children').forEach(function(child){
        console.log('is this even called?');
        result.push(child);
      });
      console.log('coz this is!');
    });
    return result;
  }.property("parents", "parents.@each.children")
});
```

Why is the second loop empty? I know data is loaded (ember inspector).. so why is it not accesible here?

**EDIT2:**

Almost there! It seems the list was empty, becouse it was a promise array (which was not yet resolved), therefore at the time the code was executed - it was empty!

```
 grandchildren: function(){
    var grandchildren = [];
    this.get('parents').forEach(function(parent) {
      var promiseArray = parent.get('children');
      promiseArray.then(function() {
        promiseArray.forEach(function(child){
          grandchildren.push(child);
          console.log(child);
        });
      });
    });
    return grandchildren;
  }.property("parents", "parents.@each.children")
```

So this code correctly displays in console log all the grandchildren... but! it still does not return them. It's probably for the same reason - at the time the code hits `return grandparent` it's still empty. I'm thinking now, is there a way around that?

**EDIT3:**

It seems the root of the problem is the `DS.hasMany('parent', { async: true })` and `DS.hasMany('child', { async: true })`. I've ommited the async part in the original question to make the model example more clear.

**EDIT4:**

I have solved my problems by removeing the `async: true` from the DS.hasMany and used [this script](http://amalgamated.io/emberjs-and-fixtures/) to load them correctly without async.

This fixed the problem with "empty arrays" (unresolved promise arrays) and allowed me to access the properties. Then I did the following code (in the MODEL's reopen function):

```
grandchildren: function(){
  var res = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: Ember.A()});

  this.get('parents').forEach(function(parent){
    res.pushObjects(parent.get('children').toArray());
  });

  return res;
}.property('parents', 'parents.@each.children')
```

And it works! Yay!

#### However, I'm still interested in the solution for ASYNC data

The next step is replaceing the fixtures with some data fetched from the server. And that data is asynchronous.. so I still need a solution with promises.

**EDIT5:** Test code:

```
grandchildren: function(){
  var res = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: Ember.A()});

  this.get('parents').forEach(function(parent) {
      var promiseArray = parent.get('children');
      promiseArray.then(function() {
        res.pushObjects(promiseArray.toArray());
      });
    });

  return res;
}.property('parents', 'parents.@each.children')
```

Comment: First, why don't you have a model `person` and say something like `parents: DS.hasMany('person')`. That will help simplify the model types.

Comment: So it looks like you might need to look into flattening your tree structure into an array for the `children` function in `Grandparent`

Comment: @claptimes i've almost solved it.. see edit2

Comment: At this point you probably want to use an `ArrayProxy`. Something like: `var grandchildren = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []})` then `pushObject`s on to the array inside your promises.

Comment: @claptimes you mean something like (see edit5)?

Comment: Yes. If you're still having issues, please add a jsbin so that I can take a closer look.

Comment: @claptimes today i'll be replaceing my fixtures with real database.. so probably my data will be async again -> and i will have to change to your proposed solution.. i'll give you info how it went

Comment: i ended up rendering my initial data as JSON in response html script tag to avoid async loading of data, becouse i have no time to learn promises right now (deadline is till tomorrow), but I will get back to this very soon (i must learn async data handleing and useing promises) and i will post my findings here

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_all.

```
var promises = [];
this.get('parents').forEach(function(parent) {
  promises.push(parent.get('children'));
});
return Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(results) {
  // return concatenated results
});
```

When you call grandchildren you will get a promise that resolves to the concatenated results.

In the future it looks like there will be support for hasMany through similar to rails.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/120